# how to add navigation inside the recent post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

[newer | older ] 
if i click newer , newer recent post will load.
either if i click older, then the next recent post will load.
I am new to wordpress. can who give me an idea to implement navigation inside this code. shown below?

```
<?php
                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
                        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                            echo '<li style="font-weight:700;"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                            echo '<li>' .wpautop(wp_trim_words($recent["post_content"], 15)). '</li>';
                        }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

what you want is the use of these two functions: [get_next_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) and [get_previous_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post)

```
$next_post = get_next_post();
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
```

Comment: how to use those function inside the recent_post container

Answer (score 1):

You can use these methods:

```
 <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( $label ); ?> // For previous post link
 <?php echo get_next_posts_link( $label ); ?> // For next post link
```

Note: if you want to know more about this then use can take a reference from these links [get_previous_posts_link( $label)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_posts_link)  and another is [get_next_posts_link( $label )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link)

Comment: how to use these function  inside the recent post? can you give me code